# What is wrong with this code? (groovy) MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy

I am trying to write a small program that reads the X and Y coordinates of three points and then outputs which of the three are closer. However I keep getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyExeption errors. Could anybody please help/explain what is wrong?

```
Point a = new Point()
print "enter first x co-ordinate: "
a.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())
println "enter first y co-ordinate: "
a.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())

Point b = new Point()
println "enter second x co-ordinate: "
b.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())
println "enter second y co-ordinate: "
b.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())

Point c = new Point()
println "enter third x co-ordinate: "
c.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())
println "enter a third y co-ordinate: "
c.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console.readLine())

double distatob = Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x) ** 2 + (a.y - b.y) **2)
double distatoc = Math.sqrt((a.x - c.x) ** 2 + (a.y - c.y) **2)
double distbtoc = Math.sqrt((b.x - c.x) ** 2 + (b.y - c.y) **2)


if (distatob < distatoc && distatob < distbtoc) {
    println ("First and second points are closest")
} else if (distatoc < distatob && distatoc < distbtoc) {
    println ("First and third points are closest")
} else if (distbtoc < disatob && distbtoc < distatoc) {
    println ("Second and third co-ordinates are closest")
} else {
    println "error"
}

class Point {
    double x
    double y
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: console for class: java.lang.System`

`System.console` is not a property. It's a method. So you'll need to call it, like this: `System.console().readLine()`.

Also a misspelled variable name `disatob` instead of `distatob`, here is the correct version:

```
Point a = new Point()
print "enter first x co-ordinate: "
a.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())
println "enter first y co-ordinate: "
a.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())

Point b = new Point()
println "enter second x co-ordinate: "
b.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())
println "enter second y co-ordinate: "
b.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())

Point c = new Point()
println "enter third x co-ordinate: "
c.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())
println "enter a third y co-ordinate: "
c.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())

double distatob = Math.sqrt((a.x - b.x) ** 2 + (a.y - b.y) **2)
double distatoc = Math.sqrt((a.x - c.x) ** 2 + (a.y - c.y) **2)
double distbtoc = Math.sqrt((b.x - c.x) ** 2 + (b.y - c.y) **2)


if (distatob < distatoc && distatob < distbtoc) {
    println ("First and second points are closest")
} else if (distatoc < distatob && distatoc < distbtoc) {
    println ("First and third points are closest")
} else if (distbtoc < distatob && distbtoc < distatoc) {
    println ("Second and third co-ordinates are closest")
} else {
    println "error"
}

class Point {
    double x
    double y
}
```