# MissingPropertyException error (groovy)

Tags: groovy

I need to write a program that reads the X and Y coordinates of two points and then outputs the area and perimeter of a rectangle where both points are opposite corners. I however get this error message

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No Such property : x for class:
>   rectangle.

Could anybody please help explain what is going wrong here?

```
    // First point
Point point1 = new Point()
print "enter first x co-ordinate: "
point1.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())
print "enter first y co-ordinate: "
point1.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())

// Second point
Point point2 = new Point()
print "enter second x co-ordinate: "
point2.x = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())
print "enter second y co-ordinate: "
point2.y = Double.parseDouble(System.console().readLine())

// Create Rectangle
Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle()
myRectangle.upLeft = point1
myRectangle.downRight = point2

// Calculate Perimeter 
double width = myRectangle.downRight.x - myRectangle.upLeft.x
double height = myRectangle.upLeft.y - myRectangle.downRight.y
double perimeter = 2 * (width + height)

// Calculate Area
double area = width x height 

println "Perimeter is " + perimeter
println "Area is " + area


class Point {
    double x
    double y
}

class Rectangle {
    Point upLeft
    Point downRight
}
```

Comment: Is this the whole code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `x` instead of `*` in the following line:

```
double area = width x height
```

should be:

```
double area = width * height
```

Anyways script runs correctly.

Comment: Right, but this is not what cause the original error, is it ? (don't know Groovy so much, I would be surprised)

Comment: It causes it as well. Try to run the OPs script in groovy console. This is where the script fails.

Comment: The OPs script fails because of the error I pointed out. However the exception message states something different.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, can't believe it was because of this silly operator error.

Comment: @max_j_r you're welcome. Don't be angry with me but it was indeed silly, just an oversight. However I upvoted the question since it was well asked - SSCCE added.

Comment: Seems to happen regularly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137834/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-groovy-missingpropertyexception ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates, looks so. Lucky to get an accept ;) Eh.. Those missing properties.. Still looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

The error explains itself :

> No Such property : x for class: rectangle.

You are using a variable of type `Rectangle` and asking for property `x` but it doesn't exist. It's `Point` class which have this property.

Comment: But as the fields of the rectangle class are points and the points that were assigned are point1 and point2 (which have property x), then myRectangle also has this property?

The code does run correctly after fixing the operator error. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: No, `rectangle.x` will never exist, `rectangle.upLeft.x` or `rectangle.downRight.y` for example does.